# How can I fix border-radius with row-styling?

Tags: html, css

I'm working with some css trying to style a table with curved corners.  But the border (white) corners on the bottom break on the bottom table row.  Basically it visually looks like the tips of the bottom left and right overflow over the rounded corners.

**Here is a working example:**  http://cssdeck.com/labs/6mpl631w

Any suggestions?

```
.table {
width: 100%;
background-color: #3F3F3F;
color:#EDEDED;
display: block;    
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
padding: 0px;
border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;

}
.table > thead > tr > th,
.table > thead > tr > td,
.table > tfoot > tr > th,
.table > tfoot > tr > td {

    padding: 8px 12px;
    }
    .table > thead > tr > th,
    .table > thead > tr > td {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .table > tfoot > tr > th,
    .table > tfoot > tr > td {
        border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
    }
.table > tbody > tr > th,
.table > tbody > tr > td {
    padding: 8px 12px;

    border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    }
    .table > tbody > tr:first-child > th,
    .table > tbody > tr:first-child > td {
        border-top-color: #cccccc;
    }
    .table > thead,
    .table > tbody > tr > th,
    .table > tfoot > tr > th {
        text-align: left;
    }

    .table > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #373737;
    }
    .table > tbody > tr.even {
        background: #373737;
    }

    .table > tbody > tr:hover {
        background: #4F4F4F;
    }
```

Comment: Which browser is giving you this issue? Are more than one giving this result? I put this together and I'm viewing it in Chrome and I'm not exactly sure what is wrong.

Comment: I'm seeing it in chrome and firefox.  I'll update with more css and maybe it'll help.

Comment: Add a live example as well please – jsfiddle or something similar.

Comment: Sure thing.  This is the first time I've ever done that.  But there is an example now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this:

```
.table {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/tvkxqtyt)

Comment: That is an awesome single line fix.  Thanks Oriol!